# Рандомное повторение действия в цикле

Tags: javascript

Есть класс в стилях .animation1 он должен вызываться постоянно (в цикле), но в рандомный промежуток и после удалятся, и повторятся снова, а то есть действие будет проигрываться в рандомный промежуток например от 1 минуты до двух и повторятся снова.

Как подобное реализовать?

Comment: повесить интервал, а таймер генерить  рандомно в диапазоне от 60000 до 120000 миллисекунд, либо рекурсивно таймаут вызывать в таком же промежутке

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, с jQuery можно сделать так:

```
//min и max минимальный и максимальный интервал в миллисекндах
function random(min, max) {
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
function animate() {
  //Тут выполняем анимацию
  //...
  console.log("Bang!");
  //Регистрируем новую анимацию
  setTimeout(animate, random(1000, 5000));
}
$(window).ready(animate);
```

Comment: только забыл в random параметры передать
И причем тут jQuery?

Comment: @pepel_xD, не забыл. min и max указываются внутри функции, потому, что потом они нигде не нужны)

Comment: ну запусти её так и посмотри в консоль....

Comment: http://f4.s.qip.ru/GjeazSvw.png выполняется однократно

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко http://f4.s.qip.ru/GjeazSvx.png так тоже не работает)

Comment: Вы не там указали действие. Я же указал в комментарии к коду место, где нужно выполнять действие. Т.е. animate убирать не стоит. Оно и отвечает за добавление нового "действия"

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @kiLLro изменил код. Вместо console.log вам нужно написать код, который выполняет анимацию, а вместо 1000 и 5000 интервал повторения действия

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко пример с выполнением анимции покажите?

Comment: @kiLLro Вы мне не дали никакой информации о вашей анимации. Ну т.е. вы сказали, что это класс, но что вы подразумеваете под анимацией? Смену класса? Покажите класс или опишите примерно анимацию

Comment: $('#selector').addClass('animation1'); и через 10 секунд $('#selector').removeClass('animation1');